# Obj-C Error "Implicit Conversion of Int to Collection * is disallowed with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios5, int, automatic-ref-counting, fmdb

```
- (void)saveCollectionMoment:(NSArray *)collectionMoments
{
    for (NSDictionary *momentData in collectionMoments) {

        int mID = [[momentData objectForKey:@"mID"] intValue];

        FMDBDataAccess *db = [[FMDBDataAccess alloc] init];
        [db insertMoment:mID toCollection: cID];
    }
}
```

the above is supposed to take an id provided from a JSON return and using FMDB update the SQLite database table with the mID and cID all i get though is the following errors.

> Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'Moment *' is disallowed with ARC

ANy help will be gratefully received.

Comment: it's clear that `insertMoment:toCollection:` method does not expect to get an `int` as the first parameter, it rather expect instance of class `Moment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `insertMoment:toCollection:` expects a `Moment*` object as its first argument, while you are trying to pass it an integer ID instead.

You should change your code to either let `insertMoment:toCollection:` accept an integer `MomentID` as its first argument, or by fetching a `Moment*` by its `MomentID` before calling the `insertMoment:toCollection:` method.

Comment: Thanks for this I will take a look, when you state Moment* do you mean that i need to use a pointer here?

Comment: @JustinErswell I'm assuming that `Moment` is an Objective-C object, and Objective-C objects are always accessed through pointers.